# check if value in the column repeats after every 7 days and filter accordingly(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

i have a following dataframe,and I have to filter students(by their IDs) who have the value "day off"every 7 days in the "Activity" column.

```
ID      Date           Activity  cumulative count
1        09-01-2018     Soccer      0
1        09-02-2018     Homework    1
1        09-03-2018     Soccer      2
.             .           .         
.             .           .
1        09-08-2018     Day Off     7
.           .             .         .
.           .             .         .
1        09-15-2018     Basketball  14
.           .              .         .
1        09-22-2018    Day Off      21
.           .              .         .
1        09-29-2018    Day Off      28
.             .            .         .
2        09-01-2018     Soccer      0
2        09-02-2018     Homework    1
2        09-03-2018     Soccer      2
.             .           .         
.             .           .
2        09-08-2018     Day Off     7
.           .             .         .
.           .             .         .
2        09-15-2018     Day off     14
.           .              .         .
2        09-22-2018    Day Off      21
.           .              .         .
2        09-29-2018    Day Off      28
.             .            .         .
```

Original Dataframe has only first 3 columns.I have added cumulative count column by doing

```
new_df_sept['cumulative count']=new_df_sept.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

AND then I have tried the following

```
new_df_sept[(new_df_sept['Activity']=='Day Off')&(new_df_sept['cumulative count']%7==0)]
```

But the above is returning rows where cumulative count is divisible by 7.It is
not checking if the Activity "week off" occurs every 7 days for each student

In the above example, ID=2 will be filtered out as it has day off every week on the same day throughout the month